# Network configuration failing fresh Ubuntu Hyper V install

Tags: networking, 20.04, hyper-v

Trying to install 20.04 LTS under Hyper-V. Setup not secure boot, 2G ram 4G max 64G vdisk, New virtual switch, all that. It all works fine to this point, then /fail.

Get to the install and it is obviously able to connect to the network, showing me web pages, can open a tab and see the anything, but then goes to add software, I see a disappearing basic message at the top of the page that it can't see the network 2 times. Then it tries to set up live patch, tells me my username and password are wrong but they are not because I have reset the password 5 times and I can log into it.

This is broken as far as I can tell. Been over guides on it, same results.

Comment: I got this working. I didn't do anything recommended. I used the default switch left that alone, and created an internal virtual switch on the hyper v side , then changed the hyper v settings to export the names of devices  to the vm, and static mac then went in the vm and created a network interface with that name and put it at automatic. Working great now over wireless and I never connected it to a wire first, and the vm does not know it is over wireless.